# SQL how not to hardcode a datediff calculation to check every month in the year against my order date

Tags: sql

What I am trying to do is assign a score based on comparing the orderdate to every month in the year. The age of the orderdate compared to the month and year is one criteria to determine the score.
So for example if the order date is within a 3 month window from the compare date the score is 100 if it's 6 months from the compare date the score is 50. The final solution needs to be as a view.

This is what I have as a sample, in my query I have two years of dates like this:

````
    select distinct 
          item, 
          orderdate,
          case when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-01-01') <= 3 
                and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-01-01') > -1 
                and returntype = 'receipt' 
                  then 100
               when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-02-01') <= 3 
                and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-02-01') > -1 
                and returntype = 'receipt' 
                  then 100
               when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-03-01') <= 3 
                and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-03-01') >- 1 
                and returntype = 'receipt' 
                  then 100

when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-01-01') <= 6 
                and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-01-01') > -6
                and returntype = 'receipt' 
                  then 50
               when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-02-01') <= 6
                and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-02-01') > --6 
                and returntype = 'receipt' 
                  then 50
               when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-03-01') <= 6
                and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-03-01') >- -6
                and returntype = 'receipt' 
                  then 50
               ELSE 0 End as returnscore
       From 
          mytable ```

Instead of doing the above and hard coding the compare date,
I want to join my table to a date table.
The date table has every date in the year as one row for a few years

So I tried creating something like
````

````
```select distinct 
      A.item, 
      A.orderdate,
      B.Date as comparedate

  From mytable A, Calendartable B where A.Orderdate >'2020-01-01'             and B.date >'2020-01-01' ```
````

````
Once I do that I am thinking to create another view that does 
''`datediff (Month, orderdate,Comparedate )```
and then do all the case when statements.


Sample data
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKutD.png
````

Comment: If you want to show your code, it's better to put three backtick before and after your code, so your code will be automatically format by stackoverflow and easier interpret by others.

Comment: backtick is the key before "1" and also make some new lines as needed.

Comment: May you also share sample data of the table?

Comment: Editing, you can also select the text to have formatting and use the double-curly bracket icon {} above the editing area.  Also.  Can you please EDIT your post and add sample data as well.  Your sample is querying the ENTIRE database.  Why not filter based on date range and such.  Also give simple explanation of what you are TRYING to do.  Leave the WHAT you are doing is fine.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem that you are trying to solve.

What does the date that you are comparing the OrderDate to mean?

I have created a SQLFiddle to help understand what you are trying to achieve.
I am assuming you are using a recent version Sql Server, SQL Server 2017 in this case.
In the new version of ReturnScore, I am using `DateFromParts()` function along with the `GetDate()` function and passing in the current year and current month, and setting the day to the 1st.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5765ae/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [Order] (
  OrderId int not null primary Key Identity (1,1),
  OrderDate datetime not null, 
)
CREATE TABLE [OrderItem](
  OrderItemId int not null primary key Identity(1,1),
  OrderId int not null,
  ItemName nvarchar(100) not null,
  ReturnType nvarchar(50) null
)
CREATE TABLE Dates
(
  Date DateTime
)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Order] ON
INSERT INTO [ORDER] (OrderId, OrderDate)
Values 
(1,'2022-06-15'),
(2,'2021-02-15'),
(3,'2022-04-15'),
(4,'2023-03-01'),
(5,'2022-09-15'),
(6,'2022-02-15')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Order] OFF
GO
Insert INTO OrderItem(OrderId, ItemName, ReturnType)
Values
(1, 'Shirt', 'receipt'),
(2, 'Pants', 'no receipt'),
(3, 'Hat', 'unknown'),
(4, 'Coat','receipt'),
(5, 'Shoes', null),
(6, 'Shirt', 'receipt')
GO
-- Dates Table
WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
INSERT INTO Dates(date)
SELECT TOP (2000) DateAdd(Day, n, '2019-12-31') FROM Nums ORDER BY n;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), '01')
SELECT 
  ItemName, 
  FORMAT(OrderDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') as 'OrderDate', 
  ReturnType,
  FORMAT(@Date,'yyyy-MM-dd') ComparedDate,
  DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, @Date) MonthDiff,
  case when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-01-01') <= 3 
            and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-01-01') > -1 
            and returntype = 'receipt' 
              then 100
           when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-02-01') <= 3 
            and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-02-01') > -1 
            and returntype = 'receipt' 
              then 100
           when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-03-01') <= 3 
            and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, '2023-03-01') >- 1 
            and returntype = 'receipt' 
              then 100
           ELSE 0 End as 'ReturnScore',
  case when DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, @Date) <= 3 
            and DATEDIFF (MONTH, orderdate, @Date) > -1 
            and returntype = 'receipt' 
              then 100
           ELSE 0 End as 'NewReturnScore'
from 
  [Order] o
  inner join OrderItem i on o.OrderId = i.OrderId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5765ae/1/0)**:

```
| ItemName |  OrderDate | ReturnType | ComparedDate | MonthDiff | ReturnScore | NewReturnScore |
|----------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------|-------------|----------------|
|    Shirt | 2022-06-15 |    receipt |   2023-03-01 |         9 |           0 |              0 |
|    Pants | 2021-02-15 | no receipt |   2023-03-01 |        25 |           0 |              0 |
|      Hat | 2022-04-15 |    unknown |   2023-03-01 |        11 |           0 |              0 |
|     Coat | 2023-03-01 |    receipt |   2023-03-01 |         0 |         100 |            100 |
|    Shoes | 2022-09-15 |     (null) |   2023-03-01 |         6 |           0 |              0 |
|    Shirt | 2022-02-15 |    receipt |   2023-03-01 |        13 |           0 |              0 |
```

Comment: Thanks this is awesome my final version will need to be a view instead of a query. And I am wondering if I can join my date table so that I do not need to hard code the compare date in every case? My date table has everyday in the year for like for years but it also has months and year date and month number. Appreciate greatly any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I will use a scheme similar to the one shown by @Natan Fischer and suggest considering another option. Assume,Orders table contains `OrderYear` and `OrderMonth` columns type int.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (OrderId int,OrderDate datetime,OrderYear int,OrderMonth int);
CREATE TABLE OrderItems(OrderItemId int, OrderId int,ItemName nvarchar(100)
  ,ReturnType nvarchar(50) );
```

Assume also that we have `Score` table as

```
CREATE TABLE Score (ReturnType nvarchar(50),FromMonth int,ToMonth int,ScoreValue int);
insert into Score values
--ReturnType  ,From, To,ScoreValue
 ('receipt'   ,  -1, 3,  100)
,('receipt'   ,  -6, 6,   50)
,('receipt'   , -12, 12,  10)
,('no receipt', -12,12,    5)
```

This table defines scorevalue for records with condition
1.ReturnType
2.Month between test date and order date
We will use this table, joined to order items an calculate score

```
declare @testdate date =cast('2022-02-01' as date); --getdate();
declare @testyear int =datepart(yy,@testdate);
declare @testMonth int =datepart(mm,@testdate);

select i.orderid,i.OrderItemId,i.ItemName,o.OrderDate,s.ScoreValue
     ,datediff(mm,orderdate,@testdate) difm1
     ,((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth)) difm2
  from orderitems i left join orders o on o.orderid=i.orderid
  left join Score s 
    on ((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth))<=ToMonth 
     and ((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth))>FromMonth 
     and i.ReturnType=s.ReturnType
```

Expresions `datediff(mm,orderdate,@testdate) difm1`
and        `((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth)) difm2`
are equal. We may use any of them.

Result query

```
select t.orderid,t.OrderItemId,min(ItemName) ItemName,min(OrderDate) OrderDate
  ,max(ScoreValue) ScoreValue
from(
  select i.orderid,i.OrderItemId,i.ItemName,o.OrderDate,s.ScoreValue
     ,datediff(mm,orderdate,@testdate) difm1  -- for debug only
     ,((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth)) difm2 -- for debug only
  from orderitems i left join orders o on o.orderid=i.orderid
  left join Score s 
    on ((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth))<=ToMonth 
     and ((@TestYear-OrderYear)*12+(@testMonth-OrderMonth))>FromMonth 
     and i.returnType=s.ReturnType
)t
group by t.orderid,t.OrderItemId
;
```

To change score calculating criteria, in many cases, it is enough to change the Score table, not Query or View.

[Test example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lbAsVS6A)